# Using useRef() in useReducer()

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have a reducer in my `useMessages()` hook. For simplicity, let's focus on the `"add"` action of my reducer, which just adds a message to an array of messages and assigns an incrementing ID to it:

```js
import { useReducer, useRef } from "react";

const useMessages = () => {
    const localMessageId = useRef(1);

    const [messages, dispatchMessages] = useReducer(
        (messages, action) => {
            switch (action.type) {
                case "add":
                    return [
                        ...messages,
                        {
                            ...action.message,
                            id: action.message.id ?? localMessageId.current++,
                        },
                    ];
                // Other actions
            }
        },
        []
    );

    return [messages, dispatchMessages, localMessageId.current];
};

export default useMessages;
```

The problem is that in Strict Mode, my ID is incremented twice, so the first message gets the ID of 2. I need to use the newly created ID after adding the message, but I'm not sure how to get this ID.

Is updating a `useRef()` value in a reducer even considered valid in React? I know that we're not supposed to run side effects in reducers, memo etc.

Comment: Just store the counter in the reducer state.

Comment: @Bergi I haven't thought about that, trying now.

Comment: @Bergi okay, so it works, but there's still another problem about it. I need to use the newly created value in there, immediately after dispatching the `"add"` action. It's a WebSocket app and I need to send the message with the new ID. I sometimes lose track of how to do these things with hooks properly.

Comment: Where is the code that sends the ws message? Is it happening in the reducer, in the action builder, in a middleware?

Comment: @Bergi nowhere of these, it's just an event handler. I'm gonna update the question.

Comment: Then probably just use the ref in there

Comment: @Bergi I changed it to use `useRef()` there and I increment it inside the `"add"` action. I return the ref (not the value) from my hook, but when I use it after dispatching the action, it still has the old value. I remember reading about it a while ago in the context of `useMemo()` and it's apparently an expected behavior. Still not sure how to properly keep tract of the last ID of my `useReducer()` though.

Comment: @Bergi I tried to ask ChatGPT, but it insists that it would change, but it does not.

Comment: @Bergi I posted another question to describe the problem there: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76451936/why-do-i-get-old-useref-value