# Why do I get old useRef() value?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I created a hook, whose purpose is adding cherries to an array:

```js
import { useReducer, useRef } from "react";

const useCherry = () => {
    const myRef = useRef(0);

    const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(
        (state, action) => {
            if (action.type === "add") {
                myRef.current += 1;
                return [...state, ""];
            }

            return state;
        },
        []
    );

    return [state, dispatch, myRef];
};

export default useCherry;
```

Then I call it on button click:

```
<button
    type="button"
    onClick={() => {
        console.log(myRef.current); // Logs 0
        dispatch({ type: "add" });
        console.log(myRef.current);// Logs 0, expected 1
    }}
>
    Add more cherry
</button>
```

I don't understand why would `cherryRef.current` return an old value after calling `dispatchCherry()`. In theory it should return the incremented one, as `myRef` is an object.

I'm trying to get the incremented value right after calling the `dispatch()`.

Comment: `dispatch({ type: "add" });` has async-like behavior, you can [read more here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64538271/is-reacts-usereducer-is-synchronous-compared-to-asynchronous-nature-of-usestate).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because [`dispatch()`](https://react.dev/reference/react/useReducer#dispatch) runs and updates the state for the next render, the second `console.log()` runs before it, and thus returns the old value.

To store and retrieve the `useRef` value before and after the change separately (outside of the `state`), consider to export a customized `dispatch()` for use in another component.

```
const myDispatchCherry = (action) => {
  if (action?.type === "add") myRef.current += 1;
  dispatch(action);
}
```

This could also keep the original `dispatch()` pure to its function, and add the additional tasks as an optional and customizable part.

Test the follow code here: [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-6ck5qm?file=src%2FApp.js)

```
import React, { useReducer, useRef } from "react";

const useCherry = () => {
    const myRef = useRef(0);
    const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(
        (state, action) => {
            if (action.type === "add") {
                return [...state, ""];
            }
            return state;
        },
        []
    );

const myDispatchCherry = (action) => {
  if (action?.type === "add") myRef.current += 1;
  dispatch(action);
}
    return {state, dispatch, myRef, myDispatchCherry};
};

export default useCherry;

export default function App() {
  const {state, myRef, myDispatchCherry} = useCherry();
  return (
    <div>
      <p>{`Cherry: ${state}`}</p>
      <button
    type="button"
    onClick={() => {
        console.log(`myRef count before adding: ${myRef.current}`); // Logs 0
        myDispatchCherry({ type: "add" });
        console.log(`myRef count after adding: ${myRef.current}`); // Logs 1
    }}
>
    Add more cherry
</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> I don't understand why would cherryRef.current return an old value
> after calling dispatchCherry(). In theory it should return the
> incremented one, as myRef is an object.

Yes, it does return the incremented value, but since it does not complete the trigger of a re-render yet, it is not shown to you (because `useRef` is not exactly a state variable). The `useState/useReducer` hook can be used to manually trigger, or you can change `myRef` to a state variable.

Example, this can give you next updated value:

```
dispatch({ type: "add" });
setTimeout(() => {
  console.log(cherryRef.current); // Logs 1
}, 0);
```

Comment: I'm literally calling `console.log()` before and after, so how is it related to "not showing it to me"?

Comment: I meant to say it does not trigger the re-render yet, just after the dispatch({ type: "add" });, try adding a sleep timer (setTimeout) to validate this.  Also, edited ans.

Comment: I know it doesn't cause re-rendering, but it has nothing to do with the problem.